# Many input files to SINGLE map. Hadoop. how?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to use only one map for many input files? Because Hadoop creates one mapper for one file. I need only one mapper for all files.

I tried to use `CombineFileInputFormat`. It had one mapper, but map input contained only one file. I need that input map value to contain data from all files (Text format) like this :

Input map value :

> data from file1.txt
>   data from file2.txt
>   data from file3.txt

```
public class WholeFileInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<NullWritable, Text> {

public WholeFileInputFormat() {
    super();
    setMaxSplitSize(67108864);
}

@Override
protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public RecordReader<NullWritable, Text> createRecordReader(
        InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {

    if (!(split instanceof CombineFileSplit)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("split must be a CombineFileSplit");
    }
    RecordReader<NullWritable, Text> r = new CombineFileRecordReader<NullWritable, Text>((CombineFileSplit) split, context, WholeFileRecordReader.class);
    return r;
    //return null;
}

}


public class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<NullWritable, Text> {

private final Text mFileText;

public WholeFileRecordReader(CombineFileSplit fileSplit, TaskAttemptContext context,
                             Integer pathToProcess) throws IOException {

    mProcessed = false;
    mFileToRead = fileSplit.getPath(pathToProcess);
    mFileLength = fileSplit.getLength(pathToProcess);
    mConf = context.getConfiguration();

    assert 0 == fileSplit.getOffset(pathToProcess);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(mConf);
    assert fs.getFileStatus(mFileToRead).getLen() == mFileLength;

    //    mFileName = new Text();
    mFileText = new Text();
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    mFileText.clear();
}


@Override
public NullWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return NullWritable.get();
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return mFileText;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return (mProcessed) ? (float) 1.0 : (float) 0.0;
}

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // no-op.
}


@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (!mProcessed) {
        if (mFileLength > (long) Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IOException("File is longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE.");
        }
        byte[] contents = new byte[(int) mFileLength];

        FileSystem fs = mFileToRead.getFileSystem(mConf);
        FSDataInputStream in = null;
        try {
            // Set the contents of this file.
            in = fs.open(mFileToRead);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
            mFileText.set(contents, 0, contents.length);

        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(in);
        }
        mProcessed = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Couldnot understand what you are trying to achieve, as you need to write only one map for all your inputs.

Comment: Jijo , I try to combine data input in 1000 files to one map input value (for one mapper). For example for 1000 files it will be 1000 mappers as i understand. It is very long. I need that text data from all files combine in one record and then used for map input value.

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers is not driven by the number of files, but by the number of blocks comprising those files; thus, Hadoop splits each file into blocks, and and a mapper is created for each one of them. Please, take a look to a link like this [one](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) in order to know more about how the number of mappers and reducers is chosen by Hadoop.

If you exactly want one mapper, it must be said that setting this parameter `mapred.map.tasks` will not work, since this is hint for Hadoop, not a mandatory paramter. You can try to increase the block size to a very high number...

Anyway, it has no sense to use a single mapper with Hadoop... you will be missing the distributed processing of the data, that is one of the advantages of such a system.